# Boot from Ubuntu live USB stick ('Try Ubuntu'). How to see USB disk contents?

Tags: live-usb

I am booting from a USB stick, using the option 'Try Ubuntu'. The USB drive contains some files that I need to see. Is there a way to see the drive contents?

Comment: I am not sure how the device will look like. Can you give me an `lsblk` and `sudo parted -l` from within the live system, please?

Comment: Will looking under `/media` not yield the mounted stick? I don't have any on me, but I vaguely recall I was able with some older ones to do just that.

Comment: When you make an live USB stick , it will format everything that was there in the usb, and will write the contents of iso files into it. You will not be able to see files other than what the iso file has. Are you looking for any specific system files?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you should know:

1) To look in a USB stick, it has to be mounted. Try mounting it with the [mount](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/mount.8.html) command. Look in your `/dev/` directory for the file to mount, it will be title sdXY, where X is a letter, usually 'b' or 'a' and Y is optional, but typically a number between 1 and 9.

2) As mentioned above, if you had files on the USB before making it a live USB, the files are reformatted and essentially gone. You can use `gparted` or a similar program to partition the drive which allows for storing files and having a Live Drive on the same key.